# Fix Rails Gem CanCan bug for ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

When attempting to create on a model with CanCan set as `manage: all` I am continuously getting this error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:

I found a fix online [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835).

That pastes this code into my applications controller:

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

This leads to my issue. I have two models with `belongs_to_has_many` association and a method that adds an user to a group.

When I want to add an user to a group using `add_user` which takes the group id and the user object I now get this error.

The routine is called by:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', add_user_group_path(group: @group, user_id: id)  %>
```

The method looks like this:

```
def add_user
  group = Group.find(params[:id])
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  group.users << user
end
```

And this is the error:

> Parameters: {"group"=>"16", "id"=>"16", "user_id"=>"332"}
>    NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for "16":String:

What is the `before_filter` method doing that would cause this error?

================ UPDATE ===================

I ended up figuring it out.

Since the group id is automatically passed in the add_user call from the controller I had to change this line:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', add_user_group_path(group: @group, user_id: id)  %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', add_user_group_path(user_id: id)  %>
```

And it now works. Turns out when you pass the @group object the param "group => x" gets parsed weird.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `CanCan` over `CanCanCan`?

Comment: Please copy in the contents of your controller so we can see what's going on there.

Comment: I actually have never heard of CanCanCan

Comment: What is the benefit of CanCanCan over CanCan?

Comment: CanCan is no longer being maintained. CanCanCan is the new version. I'd strongly recommend you to use CanCanCan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanCan is not working with Rails4. Use CanCanCan, and you don't need any of these workaround. Just have some following methods just like what we normally do in Rails4.

> create_params or update_params (depending on the action you are performing)
>
> _params such as article_params (this is the
>   default convention in rails for naming your param method)
>
> resource_params (a generically named method you could specify in each
>   controller)

Link Here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan